# Git in Visual Studio 2019 Community, ignoring cache files

Tags: git, visual-studio

I sync between laptop and desktop using Git.

It always finds clashes between certain files, .dbcache.v2, .suo, dlls in bin, .cshtml.g.cs files. So when I switch between devices I have to laboriously right click and 'take local' or 'take remote' rather than having a nice fast Git experience.

Merging should be for actual code files where there are two different edits not cache files or generated dlls.

A couple of questions (I can't find anything online about this).

Can I safely just add all these above and things like it to .gitignore? (if so what's the best way?)

If I can, why aren't these files automatically excluded when you setup a new ASP.net Core project?

The out of the box experience is awful, it involves constantly dealing with clashes in these files that you never edit and don't need to know about.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I safely just add all these above and things like it to .gitignore? (if so what's the best way?)

Yes you can.

You could generate a good `.gitignore` file for Visual Studio with https://gitignore.io (Search for "Visual Studio")

But ignoring them now that they are tracked won't be enough. You have to stop track them (with `git rm --cached`)

> The out of the box experience is awful, it involves constantly dealing with clashes in these files that you never edit and don't need to know about.

I imagine as this files that must not be tracked.